# Execute hello.c file by using file handlers in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm trying my luck with C lately and I came across to this question where I'm stuck.

I've a hello.c file

CODE 1

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

I open this file and display the content using the following C program (CODE 2)

CODE 2

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdio.h>    
int main() {

    FILE *fd;
    char ch;
    fd = fopen("/home/hello.c","r");

    if( fd != NULL ) {
        while((ch = getc( fd )) != EOF){
                putchar(ch);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I want the output of this code to be Hello World, i.e output of the hello.c file which is read.
How can that be done?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) function returns an `int`. This is rather important for that `EOF` check. So please update your variable `ch` accordingly.

Comment: As for your problem, what is the goal with the second program? To read and *parse* the source-file `hello.c`? To compile `source.c` and run the executable created?

Comment: It is best to include a newline at the end of the output in your "Hello World" program.  Either use `puts()` instead of `printf()` or add the character to the end of the string.

Comment: What do you think you use from the `<fcntl.h>` header?  When you're using file streams (`FILE *`), you very rarely need `<fcntl.h>` too.  Stylistically, it's also conventional to use `fp` for 'file pointer' and reserve `fd` for 'file descriptor'.  File descriptors have type `int` and you might well need `<fcntl.h>` when you use file descriptors (and/or `<unistd.h>`).

Answer (score 3):

In order to run a c file, first you need to compile it into machine code then execute it.

To compile it: run gcc source-file -o executable-file

To run, execute: executable-file

In order to to the same things in C, use `system()` function from `<stdlib.h>`

```
const char* tempFile = "./tempfile";
const char* sourceFile = "hello.c";

const char compileCommand[255];
sprintf(compileCommand, "gcc %s -o %s", sourceFile, tempFile);

system(compileCommand);

system(tempFile);
```

This code hasn't been tested.

Answer (score 1):

Your "CODE 2" would have to invoke a C-compiler to compile "CODE 1" and then run it using `system()` or a function provided by your operating system.

BTW: It is either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, NOT `int main()`.

Comment: Note that the C11 standard contains examples using `int main()`.  Granted, they're not normative, but it isn't wholly wrong to use `int main()` — even though I strongly recommend using `int main(void)` instead.  Don't overstate the case, that's all.  (See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for the details.)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in the second program, you are reading `hello.c` file. So the output of CODE2 will be the **contents** of `hello.c`. i.e.  `#include<stdio.h>...`

For what you need, in CODE1, you need to write the output of the program into a separate file (say `a.txt`) and then read `a.txt` in CODE2.

Hope this is a sufficient hint for you to solve further.

Answer (score 0):

As general solution, you may try also to have a look to a C interpreter, like [Cling](https://root.cern.ch/cling), and try to include it in your project.